# How to connect PC to TV using VGA to SCART?

Tags: display, vga, external-display

I am trying to connect my Acer Aspire One to my Philips 32" 32PFL3614/12 TV using VGA to SCART.

First, I have to say that I can successfully connect my PC to my 17" Philips monitor. When this happens, in Display Settings/Screen Resolution I see the two connected displays:

1. Mobile PC Display
2. Philips 170S

Back on the TV problem, when I first connected it and it did not succeed, I messed with the settings: extend, duplicate, etc. Sometimes I saw that it did allow me to select high resolutions, the ones for the TV. Additionally one time the correct TV resolution was selected by default.

However I did not see anything on the screen and cannot remember how I did this. Also, instead of showing the name of the TV, as it happens when I connect it to my 17" monitor, it shows a Generic non-PnP monitor.

What do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got myself one of these devices back when I tried this

[image: http://www.hdcabling.co.za/images/VGA_to_RCA_Svideo_VGA_Passthrough_Converter.jpg]

It worked pretty well and the signal wasn't bad. The device actively converts VGA to the composite signal.

Comment: How to search for it ?

Comment: VGA to Composite or VGA to RCA adapter.

Comment: I found this http://www.ebseller.com/images/CP_show/imagesbak/bananaplug/vga/2-1xiao.jpg but my TV has only the red, white, yellow. It does not have input for the yellow on the very right.

Comment: It doesn't matter, @Nikolai. The larger one is S-Video. It's either that or the normal yellow one. You don't need both... Though I don't know if such a converter works..

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a number of users reporting issues using SCART as there can be sync issues.  Are you able to obtain a USB to HDMI converter? While not inexpensive, they seem reliable  One example [Startech Adapter](http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-3-to-HDMI-DVI-External-Video-Card-Multi-Monitor-Adapter-1920x1080~USB32HDE)  What model of Aspire One do you have?  There are also VGA to HDMI adapters but usually more expensive.

Comment: I am using zg5. I read that vga to hdmi can not work because of the analog-digital signal...However there must be a solution for this.

Comment: I have used one of these units without issue on a Windows XP laptop connecting to my 42" Plasma http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-to-HDMI-External-Dual-or-Multi-Monitor-Video-Adapter-with-Audio~USB2HDMI