# Connecting Satellite Box to PC Monitor

Tags: display, dvi, vga, external-display

I have a satellite box which has a SCART for output and I want to connect it to an LG monitor which has a VGA connection and a DVI connection.

Is it possible with a cable or would I need some circuitry to convert the signals?

This isn't a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/q/387497/140027) as I want to the output to be SCART and the input VGA whereas that question is the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without additional hardware.

While you may find some articles that have only passive components in schematics, like this one: http://www.idiots.org.uk/vga_rgb_scart/ (sites like this warn you that all you do - you do at your own risk).

The both cables have a separate lines for the Red, Green, and Blue signals. But the synchronization signal is transferred differently in these two standards. VGA uses separate H-Sync and V-Sync signals while Scart has only one composite synchronization signal. [Here](http://pinouts.ru/VideoCables/vga2scart_scheme_pinout.shtml) you may see the schematic of a simple converter that mixes up H-Sync and V-Sync of the VGA cable into the Video sync signal. However I would propose you to find a [ready to use solution](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1/182-5422391-0859538?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=vga%20rca%20converter&rh=n:172282,k:vga%20rca%20converter)

Comment: Please expand on this answer. It is vague in its current form.

Comment: @RandolphWest done